# How calculate the integral of the volume form over $S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

> Let $\omega$ the volume $2$-form over $S^1 \times S^1$, find:
>   $$\int_{S_1 \times S_1} \omega$$

Let $I=[0, 2\pi]$. I know that a parametriaztion of $S^1$ is $\phi(\theta)=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)), \theta \in I$

Then a parametrization of $S_1 \times S_1$ is $F:I \times I \rightarrow S_1 \times S_1$ defined as $F(\theta,\varphi)=(\phi(\theta),\phi(\varphi))$. Then i need calculate:
$$\int_{S_1 \times S_1} \omega=\int_{I\times I}F^*(\omega)$$

I'm stuck here, i don't know how to calculate the pullback $F^*(\omega)$, i need charts for this?

Comment: Your parametrization is equivalent to a chart. All you need to do is pull back. What is “the” volume form to which you refer?

Comment: Hi, you seem to keep posting questions, deleting them once people comment, then reposting them as slightly different questions rather than editing the question. For example, this question is very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3577803/90543

Comment: Also you asked something similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3579115/90543) and deleted it before asking the current version, though I've lost the link now.

Comment: Nvm, found the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577803/how-integrate-this-1-form-in-s1-times-s1-times-s1